# Unable to Finetune Deberta

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to finetune deberta for irony detection task, colab's notebook link can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mZI5W2ozc8speZiwzOtCrWABhSaxqhWD?usp=sharing)

When I try to use 'microsoft/deberta-v3-base' checkpoint with AutoModel, I'm getting the following error :

```py
RuntimeError: Expected target size [32, 2], got [32]
```

but when I use the same model with 'bert-base-uncased' or roberta (with some changes in head) it works fine. The one can find working code for bert based in [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PXacY2YgAfk6IYC0sAynp88Z6ndWrqYQ?usp=sharing) notebook.

When I printed the shapes of predictions and labels, I got outputs as torch.Size([32, 30, 2]), torch.Size([32]) respectively. In the case of bert, shapes of outputs were torch.Size([32, 2]), torch.Size([32]) for predictions and labels.

Here 32 is the batch size, and 30 is the sequence length.

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Bert and Deberta have different outputs and you should try changing part of the code to something like this

```
   outputs = self.bert(**inputs)
   last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
   x = self.dropout(last_hidden_states)
```

hope it helps